# Zend Framework - applying order by on a nested query

Tags: zend-framework, zend-db-table

This might be a very simple thing. Check out the normal sql query below

```
(select * from shopping order by shopping_id desc limit 5) order by RAND()
```

This query runs successfully in mysql - not sure if this is the right way of doing it - but it works. It gets the last 5 ids from shopping table and randomly orders them everytime

I want to achieve this in Zend. I'm not sure how to execute the first part and then apply the RAND clause to the results - what I have below does not do that.

```
$select = $this->select()       
           ->from(array('sh'=>'shopping'))
           ->order('shopping_id desc')
           ->limit(5)    
           ->order('RAND()');
```

Comment: I'm fairly sure native Zend_Db won't do subqueries.  You could easily leave off the `order by RAND()` and then let your Rowset/PHP code randomize 5 entries...

Comment: @gnarf Zend_Db_Select can very much do subselects. You just have to put them into the query with a Zend_Db_Expr.

Comment: I'd follow @gnarf's suggestion considering "ORDER BY RAND()" would bypass the query cache.

Comment: Thank you - I agree with Gnarf's approach - didn't think of that approach at all - sometimes u forget the easy route and keep banging ur head....thanks guys 
@gnarf - you have not posted that as an answer so I'm not able to accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not take a slightly different approach which will acheive the same results.  If you drop the subselect and the `order by RAND()` you can get the rows very quickly from the database, then when you are working with the rows, you could always randomize them.

```
$select = $this->select()       
       ->from(array('sh'=>'shopping'))
       ->order('shopping_id desc')
       ->limit(5)    

$rows = $this->fetchAll($select);

// take it from a rowset object, convert to an array:
$rowArray = array();
foreach ($rows as $row) $rowArray[] = $row;
shuffle($rowArray);
```

Comment: @Gublooo - Here you go, a version of my comment worthy of being an answer :)

Answer (score 1):

The Zend_Db_Expr class lets you do that. You create a new instance of the Zend_Db_Expr class and using its constructor you pass in the expression as a string: "RANDOM()".

$select = $this->select()
           ->from(array('sh'=>'shopping'))
           ->order('shopping_id desc')
           ->limit(5)
           ->order(new Zend_Db_Expr('RANDOM()'));